# Error: Use of undeclared identifier NSOpenPanel in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm getting the following error:

> Use of undeclared identifier NSOpenPanel

```
NSOpenPanel *panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
[panel setCanChooseFiles:NO];
[panel setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
[panel setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES]; // yes if more than one dir is allowed 
NSInteger clicked = [panel runModal];
if (clicked == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) 
{
    for (NSURL *url in [panel URLs]) 
    {
        // do something with the url here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSOpenPanel` is not available in `iOS`, only under `macOS` (`Cocoa`).

You can not let the user browse the file system under `iOS`. You can browse certain file types though, using Apples public API. For instance you can let the user choose images using [UIImagePickerController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller)

Comment: How to open file picker in in objective-c? Can u send sample code for it

Comment: There is no file picker under iOS.

Comment: then how to browse for files programmatically?

Comment: I want to choose a file and upload from iphone client to server

Comment: You can not reach the file system under iOS. Check sandboxing: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html

Comment: then how to upload files from Iphone?

Comment: I think @shallowThought's answer is pretty self explanatory and comprehensive. You can't use a native file browser, because iOS doesn't really expose the concept of a "file system" to the user. If you store files on your own (e.g., in the user's sandboxed Documents directory), then you'll have to roll your own or use a library like https://github.com/marmelroy/FileBrowser

Comment: Can you send sample objectie-c code. as im not familiar with swift